# Jquery not returning false and continue executing the rest of the code

Tags: jquery, asp.net

net application with jquery. I have one button and gridview with checkbox. If none of the checkboxes are checked i dont want to button to fire and go to server side. I am trying as below.

This is my button.

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnRegretletter" runat="server" Text="Send Regret Letter" class="submitLink blueButton" OnClientClick="javascript:check()" OnClick="btnRegretletter_Click" ValidationGroup="VGsubmit" />
```

This is my jquery code.

```
 function check() {
        alert("I have been called");
        var valid = false;
        var ResultArrayFirst = [];
        $('#<%= gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> input[type="hidden"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
            {
                ResultArrayFirst.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        alert(ResultArrayFirst);
        if (ResultArrayFirst.length > 0) {
            valid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please select at least one vendor to send Regret Letter.");
            valid = false;
            return valid;
        }
 $("#<%=gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            //Skip first(header) row
            if (!this.rowIndex) return;

            var status = $(this).find("td:last").text().trim();
            if (status == "Awarded" || status == "Rejected") {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
            }
     });
}
```

In the above code whenever i dont select any checkboxes from gridview my variable will be null and my else part should execute. I am able to fire alert but as soon as my alert fires and clicks on ok my page refreshes and it will got to server side. May I know how can i prevent? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return valid;` should be outside else part like following snippet, because in your case if length would be greater than 0 function will not return.

```
if (ResultArrayFirst.length > 0) {
   valid = true;
}
else
{
    alert("Please select at least one vendor to send Regret Letter.");
    valid = false;
}
return valid;
```

Plus you need to check it like this :

```
OnClientClick="return check()"
```

You can also check it like following snippet:

```
OnClientClick="if (!check()) { return false;};"
```

Comment: But I am doing some other caluculation also inside check function. I will post the code above and that block of code is not working now. May i know the reason please?

Comment: did you change this `OnClientClick="javascript:check()"` to `OnClientClick="return check()"` @NiranjanGodbole

Comment: Plus do you get the `alert` Please select at least one vendor to send Regret Letter. ? @NiranjanGodbole

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole you dont need to assign `valid = false;` its already `false`. change your `OnClientClick`

Answer (score 1):

You are not consuming the `return` value of `check()` method.

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="return check()" />
```

Additionally, not all code path in your function returns value.

```
function check() {
    //Your existing code

    //Add the statement at end of function
    return valid;
}
```